# Pass dynamic params in the ajax call of yii2-grid EditableColum widget

Tags: yii2, x-editable, yii2-widget

the [\kartik\grid\EditableColumn](http://demos.krajee.com/grid#editable-column) widget has a parameter called ajaxSettings where you may override the parameters passed with the ajax request to the server. What i want to do is to dynamically pass the selected rows ids together with the value coming from the popover to the server. I manage to do that passing static parameter coming from a php array in compile time like so

```
Editable::widget(['name' => 'publishDate', 'ajaxSettings' => ['ids' => [1,2,3]]])
```

but It seems that i cannot use a jquery selector there to grab the ids of the selected columns like so

```
Editable::widget([
    'name' => 'publishDate', 
    'ajaxSettings' => [
        'ids' => '$("#books-grid").yiiGridView("getSelectedRows")'
    ]
])
```

Comment: Interesting question. Need to do some testings to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try creating a variable outside the Editable::widget([ like this:

```
var arrayIds = $("#books-grid").yiiGridView("getSelectedRows");
```

And then assign it to the widget:

```
Editable::widget([
    'name' => 'publishDate', 
    'ajaxSettings' => [
        'ids' => arrayIds
    ]
])
```

Hope this helps,

Leo.

Comment: I tried to, but the ids come dynamically from the selected checkboxes of the grid and this seems to break the override of the data parameter in the ajax call.

Comment: I believe that you need to convert the array from the yiiGridView to an indexed array? Could you try converting the array to an indexed array using this function?

newArray = $.makeArray( arrayIds );